# Why "mvn deploy" command is rebuilding .jar?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, maven-profiles

I am working on the `spring-boot` java application. I am trying to build and publish `.jar` using maven with profile.but somehow `mvn deploy` command rebuilds `.jar` again.

`option 1:`I used `mvn clear install -Pdev` and did `mvn deploy -Dmaven.install.skip=true`without profile and its deploying default `.jar` file

`option 2:` I passed profile id during publish too.`mvn deploy -Dmaven.install.skip=true` ITs working fine but its rebuilding everything again and we do not want to use maven profile name again during `mvn deploy`

`pom.xml`

```
<project...>
 ...
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profile.id>dev</spring.profile.id>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profile.id>prod</spring.profile.id>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

`mvn clean install -Pdev`

```
 [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.1.2:jar (default-jar) @ xyz- 
 profile 
 [INFO] Building jar: /sys_apps_01/jenkins/workspace/xyz-profile-0.0.3- 
 SNAPSHOT.jar
```

`mvn deploy`  `mvn deploy -Pdev`

```
I am getting below logs for both deploy command:

[DEBUG] isUp2date: false (Destination /sys_apps_01/jenkins/workspace/xyz- 
profile-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar not found.)
[INFO] Building jar: /sys_apps_01/jenkins/workspace/xyz-profile-0.0.3- 
SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Can anyone help me to understand,why its rebuilding again while deploy ?

Comment: You are starting the build life cycle which means to start from the beginning...

Answer (score 2):

You should read about Maven lifecycle for understand what is happening : **https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html**

So when you're doing a `deploy` command maven trigger all previous goal in the lifecycle :

- validate
- compile
- test
- package
- verify
- install

Then `deploy`

Comment: Thanks for documenting this.  So with something like a command where you tell it to just promote a jar previously built `deploy -DmuleDeploy -DskipTests -Dmule.artifact=$JAR_NAME` I noticed it still made a 1.0.x version of a jar still even though I told it to just use a artifact.  Is there a way to disable it from wasting CI/CD time on a redundant task?